# Lint report "Hardcoded Package in Namespace"

Tags: android, xml, lint, hardcode

today when I want to get a release from my project , android studio show this errorr:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

So I open report folder of lint and see this error:

```
<issue
    id="ResAuto"
    severity="Fatal"
    message="In Gradle projects, always use `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` for custom attributes"
    category="Correctness"
    priority="9"
    summary="Hardcoded Package in Namespace"
    explanation="In Gradle projects, the actual package used in the final APK can vary; for example,you can add a `.debug` package suffix in one version and not the other. Therefore, you should **not** hardcode the application package in the resource; instead, use the special namespace `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` which will cause the tools to figure out the right namespace for the resource regardless of the actual package used during the build."
    errorLine1="    xmlns:app=&quot;http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ir.app.appname&quot;>">"
    errorLine2="               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    quickfix="studio">
    <location
        file="C:\...\app\src\main\res\color\mybutton_backgroundcolor.xml"
        line="3"
        column="16"/>
</issue>
```

mybutton_backgroundcolor.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ir.app.appname">

    <item android:state_enabled="true" app:state_read ="false" android:color="@color/backgrpund_button_success"/>

    <item android:state_enabled="false" app:state_read ="false" android:color="@color/gray_4"/>
    <item app:state_read ="true" android:color="@color/gray_4"/>

</selector>
```

the error is in this **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ir.app.appname">** line.

Can some one help me to solve this problem?!

**Update:**
this error occur after I update `com.android.support` library to version 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app` namespace should be declared as `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`:

As the Lint says:

> In Gradle projects, the actual package used in the final APK can vary;
>   for you can add a `.debug` package suffix in one version and not the
>   other. Therefore, you should *not* hardcode the application package in
>   the resource; instead, use the special namespace
>   `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` which will cause the tools
>   to figure out the right namespace for the resource regardless of the
>   actual package used during the build.